# LQG Demystified Book?

Tags: resource-recommendations, loop-quantum-gravity

Does a similar easy to read introduction like David Mc Mohan's Demystified books exist for LQG? I'd like something easier to start with than a paper but deeper than a popular book.

Answer (score 3):

This answer contains some additional resources that may be useful. **Please note that answers which simply list resources but provide no details are strongly discouraged by [the site's policy on resource recommendation questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4697/are-resource-recommendations-allowed)**. This answer is left here to contain additional links that do not yet have commentary.

---

[A First Course in Loop Quantum Gravity](http://www.amazon.co.uk/First-Course-Loop-Quantum-Gravity/dp/0199590753/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1318838622&sr=8-1) by Gambini and Pullin sounds like what you were looking for, but the following articles and papers may also be relevant. These are roughly in increasing order of length and difficulty.

Smolin, "Atoms of Space and Time," Scientific American, Jan 2004 (the PDF is easy to find on the web by googling)

Baez, slides from a talk titled "Spin Networks, Spin Foams, and Quantum Gravity," http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/foam/

Carlo Rovelli, Peush Upadhya, "Loop quantum gravity and quanta of space: a primer," 1998, http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9806079

Rovelli, 2010, "Simple model for quantum general relativity from loop quantum gravity" -- http://arxiv.org/abs/1010.1939

Rovelli, 2010, “Loop quantum gravity: the first twenty-five years,” http://arxiv.org/abs/1012.4707

Rovelli, 2011, "Zakopane lectures on loop gravity" -- http://arxiv.org/abs/1102.3660

Rovelli, C. & Vidotto, F. 2015, [*Covariant Loop Quantum Gravity: An Elementary Introduction to Quantum Gravity and Spinfoam Theory*](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9781107706910). Described in Rovelli's website as a "straightforward introduction to LQG".